# How do I find new chapters?

Tags: another-case-solved

I have completed all secret cases and all three chapters. How do I find new chapters? I've mastered all the cases. It says to wait for an update for new cases, is this true?

Answer (score 2):

That's just it. Wait for an update to the game.

The assumption is that the developers are working on more cases to be added to the game. Once they are done, they will update the game to add the new cases. Hopefully for free.

Your best bet is to update the game ever time an update is available. (On iOS, there will be a notification in the App Store.)

Untill then, there are still the newspare jobs.

Answer (score 1):

You should complete all the newspaper cases so when new cases are released you can play unlimited.